# multiple select element - onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select element that allows for multiple selections. I'd like to display the selected values in another part of the page (in a div or something) as the user makes changes to what is selected.

Is the only way of doing this to iterate over the "options" and check if "selected" is true? this would not be preferable since each "onchange" event would require the entire select element to be iterated over.

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates how I am currently doing it, but I'm hoping maybe there's a better way than having to iterate over all the options on every "change": [multiple select elment onchange fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codecraig/2mSUS/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on a multiple select returns an array.

See the snippet below as an example:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#fruits').change(function(e) {
        var selected = $(e.target).val();
        console.dir(selected);
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="true" id="fruits">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="grape">Grape</option>
    <option value="watermelon">watermelon</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 9):

In your fiddle, I just used `.val()`. This returns an array

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/2mSUS/4/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#fruits').change(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you could use jQuery it might be as easy as:

```
$('select').change(function() {alert($(this).val())})
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
    $('#fruits').change(function(e) {
        var selected = $(e.target).val();
        console.dir(selected);
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="true" id="fruits">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="grape">Grape</option>
    <option value="watermelon">watermelon</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use blur instead of change, so that the select is only processed once, rather than on each selection. http://jsfiddle.net/2mSUS/3/

Comment: This isn't appropriate as @codecraig has said "as the user makes changes to what is selected"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [:selected Selector of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) instead, but I believe that under the hood, jQuery does a loop on the selected = true.

Answer (score 0):

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(){alert(this.value)})
```

This is a solution in JS, you can port it over to jQuery pretty easily.  The idea is to add a click listener to each option in the selection. This will not work in IE8 and below because of `addEventListener`, there are ways to get around this though.

I think this is a better approach then having to reiterate over the list.  You will have to have a listener attached to each option though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a form submit. My template helper looks like this:

```
 'submit #update': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var obj_opts = event.target.tags.selectedOptions; //returns HTMLCollection
    var array_opts = Object.values(obj_opts);  //convert to array
    var stray = array_opts.map((o)=> o.text ); //to filter by: text, value or selected
    //stray is now ["Test", "Milk Free"] for example, depending on the selection
    //...do stuff...
}
```

You could use a similar pattern for 'onchange'

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
var MyControl = document.getElementById('Control_ID');
var newValue = MyControl[MyControl.selectedIndex].value;
```

Of course, Control_ID is the ID of the select control.

Comment: This does not answer the question how to deal with multiple selected values.