# How to get value of only latest change in Bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using [Bootstrap selectpicker](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) for a select box which is populated by javascript as so:

```js
function loadFuel(){
  $.post('include/get_fueltypes.php',{}, function(data, status){

      $(".fueltype").each(function(){
        if ( $(this).children().length == 0 ) {
          $(this).append(data);
        }
      });
      $(".fueltype").selectpicker('refresh');
    });
}
```

```html
   <select class="fueltype" id="fueltype1" title="Select fuels" multiple></select>
```

I'm having trouble with finding a way of getting only the latest change out from the selectbox. Documentation doesn't really help more than getting me ALL selected values in an array, using `$("#fueltype1").selectpicker('val')`.

But want I really need is the value of only the latest selection or unselection. This meaning that an array of all values is useless. An idea I had was comparing the val-arrays given by `.selectpicker('val')`, but there has to be a more efficient way?

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551680/multiple-select-element-onchange

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple select element - onchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551680/multiple-select-element-onchange)

Comment: @RavinderPayal That question is about gett all values. I need the latest selected (or deselected) and only the latest.

Comment: Use array in memory. Compare it with newly selected values and you will get the latest change.

Comment: @RavinderPayal Yeah, I wrote in my question text that I've thought of that but that there has to be a better way.

Comment: @RavinderPaya l don't expect people that are not familiar with selectpicker to answer. If you don't know any fair suggestion, don't bother stating that.

Comment: @RavinderPayal So you went through the docs, without finding any answer, and your reply is to go through the docs? What a great helper. Keep out, please.